# How Linux Pressure Stall Information actually works

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cpu, kubernetes

I have been doing some background reading about PSI introduced in Linux 4.20. PSI gives an indication of how contended resources such as CPU, memory and IO are. This can be a very useful metric to root cause performance problems. So my assumption is the higher the PSI of a certain resource e.g. cpu obtained from `/proc/pressure/cpu` the more contention in that node for that node. To study the behaviour I ran a simple experiment in our Kubernetes cluster. I used the following pod configuration: The node the pod is deployed on has 88 cores.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: stress-ng
  labels:
    app: stress-ng
spec:
  containers:
  - name: stress-ng
    image: alexeiled/stress-ng:latest
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    command: [ '/stress-ng' ]
    args:
    - --matrix
    - '5000'
    - -t
    - '5m'
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "5000Mi"
        cpu: "5000m"
      limits:
        memory: "5000Mi"
        cpu: "5000m"
  nodeName: stressed-node1
```

Although this pod uses just 5 cores but within 30 seconds the PSI rose to almost 90% as shown below
[image]

while the average CPU utilisation of the node is very low (< 5%).

My understanding is the overall system is not contended, the high PSI, in this case, is just due to this apparent workload configuration, I would assume that the calculation would take into account the global system state:

so my questions are:

- How is PSI actually calculated?
- Is PSI misleading in this case or am I missing something?

I will appreciate any pointers.